# How to find definition of predicate in YAGO like domain,range,comment?

Tags: dataset, rdf, predicate, prefix, knowledge-graph

Thesedays I have been struggling to construct a new dataset with opensource dataset.
The first opensource dataset I downloaded is YAGO4.5. I have to take all the predicates of triples and analyse these predicates. In general, I can find the definition information like domain, range, comment(it helps me to figure out the meaning of predicate) from the URI prefix.
let me show an example, if I'm gonna find the information of

```
@prefix sh: <http://www.w3.org/ns/shacl#> .
sh:path
```

I can visit the prefix URL to find the information of `sh:path`. The URL leads to a file page which contains information of all predicates prefixed with sh: which is convenient to me.
It's like this
[image]
But when it comes to

```
@prefix ys: <http://yago-knowledge.org/schema#> .
@prefix yago: <http://yago-knowledge.org/resource/> .
ys:fromClass 
yago:appearsIn
```

This kind of predicates with prefix yago: and ys:, I can't get the information by visiting the prefix URL.
BTW I haven't find the file of information of wikidata's predicates with prefix as shown below, either.

```
@prefix pr: <http://www.wikidata.org/prop/reference/> .
@prefix prv: <http://www.wikidata.org/prop/reference/value/> .
@prefix prn: <http://www.wikidata.org/prop/reference/value-normalized/> .
```

I know sometimes the prefix URL won't directly lead me to a file page. I mean sometimes it needs to explore the website to get the information. But I have explored the website of yago thoroughly and used the SPARQL service to query in the website. I still can't find the domain, range, comment of these predicates. Maybe it just dosen't provide these information. But I did find some description concerning the relations(predicates) as shown below.
[image]
But I don't know how to find the mapping relations.
I want to know whether there are some general ways to find the definition information of predicates. And Is there any ways to consult YAGO developers link a github issue.
To be clear, my purpose is to find information of predicate's domain, range and comment. it is like as blow

```
owl:assertionProperty a rdf:Property ;
      rdfs:label "assertionProperty" ;
      rdfs:comment "The property that determines the predicate of a negative property assertion." ;
      rdfs:domain owl:NegativePropertyAssertion ;
      rdfs:isDefinedBy <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#> ;
      rdfs:range rdf:Property .
```

Comment: not all data you find in public SPARQL endpoints or RDF datasets for download is hosted as Linked Data which you're referring to - this would need a separate Linked Data server besides the exposed SPARQL endpoint. If you want to get information about a property in YAGO 4.5, then you can query the public SPARQL endpoint e.g. with `DESCRIBE <URI>`

Comment: by the way, there are not triples using `yago:appearsIn`, so are you sure that this property exists?

Comment: SHACL: https://www.w3.org/TR/shacl/, Wikidata: https://m.mediawiki.org/wiki/Wikibase/Indexing/RDF_Dump_Format There should be appropriate `rdfs:seeAlso` or `rdfs:isDefinedBy`.

Comment: I'm sure that ```yago:appearsIn``` exists. I have used public SPARQL endpoint to query it, but I can only get some triples with ```yago:appearsIn``` as predicate or object. I mean I can't retrieve the triples with ```yago:appearsIn``` as subject. So I can't get information like its ```rdfs:domain```, ```rdfs:range```, ```rdfs:comment```. BTW what do you mean by "a separate Linked Data server". @UninformedUser

Comment: To be clear, my purpose is to find information of predicate's ```domain```, ```range``` and ```comment```. it is like as blow ```owl:assertionProperty a rdf:Property ;
     rdfs:label "assertionProperty" ;
     rdfs:comment "The property that determines the predicate of a negative property assertion." ;
     rdfs:domain owl:NegativePropertyAssertion ;
     rdfs:isDefinedBy <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#> ;
     rdfs:range rdf:Property . ```

Comment: you're right, there are triples with the property. I used `http://yago-knowledge.org/schema#appearsIn`, because I thought that this is the appropriate namespace for schema entities - my bad. By Linked Data server, I meant basically some infrastructure that gives you the main principle of Linked data. tha<t is what you described in your examples, given a URI of any RDF entity, following the link and get additional data about that resource. That is the main priciple of Linked Data. Dereferencable URIs.

Comment: And that is something a SPARQL endpoint doesn't do for you. A SPARQL endpoint is just an RDF database exposing SPARQL access via HTTP.

Comment: it looks like the schema isn't loaded in the endpoint, all I could find is a "design document" of the schema [here](https://yago-knowledge.org/data/yago4.5/design-document.pdf) which shows that `appearsIn` has domain `yago:FictionalEntity` and as range `schema:CreativeWork` - and I agree, that would be annoying to gather schema information from a PDF document. I think somewhere we could get the schema as Turtle file. Maybe in the full dump Zip file

Comment: By the way, looks like you're not the first person with that problem, there is already a Github issue: https://github.com/yago-naga/yago-4.5/issues/1

Comment: Anyway thank you for informing me that there is a pdf. I already downloaded the full dump zip of yago4.5, Indeed, there is a schema.ttl which I have uploaded to my github repository https://github.com/xilixii/learngit in case you want to access to that. But it is kinda hard for me to get properties of predicates from that. It used ```sh:path```, ```sh:node``` and ```ys:fromProperty``` to explain a property which I don't fully understand right now, maybe you can check on that. @UninformedUser

Comment: I have post my questions on github.com/yago-naga/yago-4.5/issues/1. It is hard to edit my contents in this comment area.